# Official Fedora package for 'xxd' command?

Tags: yum, fedora-21, xxd

I need to use a script based upon `xxd`, but it's not installed on my Fedora 21:

```
$ xxd
bash: xxd: command not found
```

So I tried without success to search and install it:

```
$ yum install xxd
(fails)
$ yum search xxd
(fails)
$ yum search all xxd
(fails - detailed log below)
Loaded plugins: langpacks
================================================================= Matched: xxd ========
perl-Data-HexDump-XXD.noarch : Format hexadecimal dump like xxd
xxdiff.i686 : Graphical file and directories comparator and merge tool
xxdiff-tools.i686 : Tools for xxdiff
```

- **Do you know which package `xxd` is provided with?** (I mean an official package to install with `yum` from the fedora repositories).

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 51, accepted):

`xxd` is in the `vim-common` package.

You can find that by using `yum whatprovides '*bin/xxd'`.

Comment: Also works with DNF: `dnf provides '*bin/xxd'` (`whatprovides` and `prov` are aliases for `provides`).

Answer (score 27):

Have you tried

```
yum install vim-common
```